# How to convert a key value pipe delimited file into a perfect csv file with header

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Hi I have a file in the format.

```
key1=abc||key2=ajdskj||name=ankush||contact=123444
key1=def||name=reddy||contact=456778
key1=aef||address=ashaskawe||name=john
```

how to convert this to any delimited file with header using python. like

```
key1||key2||name||contact||address
abc||ajdskj||ankush||123444||NULL
def||NULL||reddy||456778||NULL
aef||NULL||john||NULL||ashaskawe
```

could you please let me know what could be the approach if there is more number of fields.

Am trying to use a csv reader and pandas to read the file but I don't have an idea of how to separate the keys and values.

Thanks for you help

Comment: I think its better solvable using `dictionary/defaultdict` if you are open to it. Let me know.

Comment: @everestial007 hi am open to use anything there is not limitations in using any functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach that uses tools from the standard library and maintains the order of the columns. The `messy_data.txt` file contains the original data and `cleaner_data.txt` is where the cleaner data is saved:

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

with open('messy_data.txt') as infile, open('cleaner_data.txt','w') as outfile:
    whole_data = [x.strip().split("||") for x in infile]
    headers = []
    for x in whole_data:
        for k in [y.split("=")[0] for y in x]:
            if k not in headers:
                headers.append(k)
    whole_data = [dict(y.split("=") for y in x) for x in whole_data]
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for header in headers:
        for d in whole_data:
            output[header].append(d.get(header,'NULL'))
    output = OrderedDict((x,output.get(x)) for x in headers)
    outfile.write("||".join(list(output.keys()))+"\n")
    for row in zip(*output.values()):
        outfile.write("||".join(row)+"\n")
```

This should yield:

```
key1||key2||name||contact||address
abc||ajdskj||ankush||123444||NULL
def||NULL||reddy||456778||NULL
aef||NULL||john||NULL||ashaskawe
```

#### Edit:

A more debug-friendly script:

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

with open('messy_data.txt') as infile, open('cleaner_data.txt','w') as outfile:
    whole_data = [x.strip().split("||") for x in infile]
    headers = []
    for x in whole_data:
        for k in [y.split("=")[0] for y in x]:
            if k not in headers:
                headers.append(k)
    #whole_data = [dict(y.split("=") for y in x) for x in whole_data]
    whole_data2 = []
    for x in whole_data:
        temp_list = [y.split("=") for y in x]
        try:
            temp_dict = dict(temp_list)
            whole_data2.append(temp_dict)
        except:
            print(temp_list)
            continue
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for header in headers:
        for d in whole_data2:
            output[header].append(d.get(header,'NULL'))
    output = OrderedDict((x,output.get(x)) for x in headers)
    print(output)
    outfile.write("||".join(list(output.keys()))+"\n")
    for row in zip(*output.values()):
        outfile.write("||".join(row)+"\n")
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: hi @Abdou is there any way we can simplify the whole_data = [dict(y.split("=") for y in x) for x in whole_data]
into nested for loops am having some issue with the data inorder to debug that I have to split this line and print the values when there is an error.
AM getting an error saying that dictionary update sequence element #0 has lenght 1; 2 required.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I made some edits, but where do you think the issue is arising from?

Comment: when we are converting from a list to a dict it is throwing an error saying that dictionary update sequence element #0 has lenght 1l 2 is required.

Comment: Seems like your actual data is different from the mock data you have here. Seems to me that there is something that is not in the form `string=string`.

Comment: Thanks abdou your code works good there is no issue with the code.
Am having issue with the data.
Am changing my code to handle that. Thank You.

Comment: The exception handling part of the new script should handle the dictionary creation that is causing the issue. The variable `temp_list` should contain 2-element lists. If any of those lists happens to only have 1 element, then there will be an error.

Comment: Hey sorry to extend this conversation.
How to handle memory error and unicode characters in the script.
I will try to make some changes and I will let you know if in case I find any solution.

Comment: I would recommend that you ask a new question concerning memory error along with unicode character issues. It's easier when questions are separated; it makes it easier for someone to provide enough attention to the particular question.

Answer (score 2):

A pandas solution :

Reading the file :

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv',delimiter='|',header=None)
dfu=df.unstack().dropna()
keys,values=np.array(dfu.apply(lambda s:str.split(s,'=')).tolist()).T
```

Making the DataFrame :

```
data=dfu.to_frame()
data['keys']=keys
data['values']=values
final=data.reset_index().pivot(
index='level_1',columns='keys',values='values')

keys       address contact key1    key2    name
level_1                                        
0             None  123444  abc  ajdskj  ankush
1             None  456778  def    None   reddy
2        ashaskawe    None  aef    None    john
```

Comment: Hi Thank You for your answer.
Could you please let me know how to handle the _csv.error line contains null byte.
on df=pd.read_csv('data.csv',delimiter='[|]+',header=None,engine='python')

Comment: probably all the file doesn't  respect the format you show. Can you give a link on (a sample of) your file to analyze that ?

Comment: it is a file with almost million rows and the size is some what close to 2GB I don't know where is the issue exactly.

Comment: you can try with df=pd.read_csv('data.csv',delimiter='|',header=None,error_bad_lines=False)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if pandas can do it or not, but I took a long approach (its not that bad) of separating the keys myself.

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#Mimic opening a file with StringIO
in_file = StringIO(u"""\
key1=abc||key2=ajdskj||name=ankush||contact=123444
key1=def||name=reddy||contact=456778
key1=aef||address=ashaskawe||name=john
""")

#First loop through the lines to find all the fields
#Also store each line info as a dict
all_line_dicts = []
all_fields = set()
for line in in_file.readlines():
    line_dict = dict(pair.split('=') for pair in line.strip().split('||'))
    all_line_dicts.append(line_dict)
    all_fields = all_fields.union(line_dict.keys())

#Now loop through the line dicts and fill each field
#Put 'NULL' if the field is not given
field_dicts = {field:[] for field in all_fields}
for line_dict in all_line_dicts:
    for field in field_dicts:
        field_dicts[field].append(line_dict[field] if field in line_dict else 'NULL')

#Convert to dataframe by pandas for simplicity
df = pd.DataFrame(field_dicts)
print df #<-- look at it
df.to_csv('test.csv',index = False) #<-- save it as a CSV
```

OUTPUT:

```
 address contact key1    key2    name
0       NULL  123444  abc  ajdskj  ankush
1       NULL  456778  def    NULL   reddy
2  ashaskawe    NULL  aef    NULL    john
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex approach, easy to maintain:

```
 import re
 f = open('test.txt', 'r').readlines()
 print('key1', 'key2', 'name', 'contact', 'address', sep='||')
 for line in f:
     if re.search('key1=(\w+)', line):
          k1 = re.search('key1=(\w+)', line).group(1)
      else:
          k1 = 'NULL'
      if re.search('key2=(\w+)',line):
          k2 = re.search('key2=(\w+)',line).group(1)
      else:
          k2 = 'NULL'
      if re.search('address=(\w+)',line):
          a = re.search('address=(\w+)',line).group(1)
      else:
          a = 'NULL'
      if re.search('name=(\w+)', line):
          n = re.search('name=(\w+)', line).group(1)
      else:
          n = 'NULL'
      if re.search('contact=(\w+)', line):
          c = re.search('contact=(\w+)', line).group(1)
      else:
          c = 'NULL'
      print(k1, k2, n, c, a, sep=' || ')
```

output:

```
 key1||key2||name||contact||address
 abc || ajdskj || ankush || 123444 || NULL
 def || NULL || reddy || 456778 || NULL
 aef || NULL || john || NULL || ashaskawe
```